# Adding Admin to page to an e-commerce website

Tags: html, node.js, web-services

A friend of mine want me to help him develop a website and admin interface to it.

The admin interface is to help him be able to write plain text that get updated on his website.

Please How do I go about this.
It’s my first time doing such

I’m trained in Vue.js, MYSQL & basics of Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very specific. What you are essentially talking about is a content management system.

If i were you, i would build the frontend with Vue and then use a headless CMS like Strapi for the database and admin interface! Strapi has an API your vue-site can consume to showcase the content.